# Разные APK для разных API

Tags: android

С выходом API 23 (Android 6) появилась необходимость билдить разные АПК для всех версий до 23, и для 23 лично. Причиной этому послужили изменения в работе с `Bluetooth`. Теперь для того, чтобы обнаруживать ближайшие устройства требуется доп. permission.
Поэтому решено выкакить очередное обновление в виде двух разных АПК - для 23 с этим пермишеном, для всех остальных - без него.

Возникают вопросы:

1. Как произойдет обновление, если выкатить 2 разных версии? Корректно ли обновится приложение на API <23 и на API 23?
   ̶2̶.̶ ̶Ч̶т̶о̶ ̶п̶р̶о̶и̶з̶о̶й̶д̶е̶т̶ ̶в̶ ̶с̶л̶у̶ч̶а̶е̶,̶ ̶е̶с̶л̶и̶ ̶у̶с̶т̶р̶о̶й̶с̶т̶в̶о̶ ̶о̶б̶н̶о̶в̶и̶т̶с̶я̶ ̶д̶о̶ ̶A̶P̶I̶ ̶2̶3̶?̶

> If you publish different APKs for different versions of Android (for
>   different API levels), then when a user's device receives a system
>   update that qualifies them for a different APK you've published,
>   Google Play updates the user's application to the APK designed for the
>   higher version of Android. Any system data associated with the
>   application is retained (the same as with normal application updates
>   when using a single APK).

Исходя из вышенаписанного, при обновлении версии Android, если есть более подходящий APK, то он будет установлен, как обычное обновление.

Comment: да по API конкретно обновится. если обновили версию андроида, и он перешел на API выше, тогда скачается APK для нового API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нужно сделать 2 APK файла с разными `versionCode`. Старше `versionCode` должен быть у APK, предназначенного для более новых версий Android, в данном случае для 23+.
2. Младшую версию ненужно ограничивать максимальной версией Android (`maxSdkVersion`).
3. Первым нужно заливать версию для всех телефонов. После нее - для API 23+. Таким образом для всех телефонов будет доступна более "*старая*" версия, а для API 23+ более "*новая*". В ситуации, когда для определенного дивайса доступны две версии сразу, будет установлена более "*новая*"